# How to select the keyword in a string list in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables called *tb_student (id,name,age,sex)* and *tb_course (id,namelist,title)*.

For example, *tb_student* data is:

```
id  name   age sex
1   Tommy  11   1
2   Marry  11   0
3   Mike   11   1
4   Lucy   10   0
```

And *tb_course* data is:

```
id  namelist    title
1   Tommy,Lucy  math
2   Marry,Tommy English
```

Now if I want to get the student who selected math, I could write the sql as:

```
select * from tb_student where 
FIND_IN_SET(name,(select namelist from tb_course where title='math'));
```

It is OK, it returns 'Tommy' and 'Lucy'.

But now if I have a student called `Tom` and he doesn't select math, my sql returns `Tom` as well.

How to change my code? Do I need to define a function to loop the namelist?

Comment: Normalize your data. In this case, use the student_id as well. `id, student_id, title` with the data `1, 1, math`, `2, 4, math`, `3, 2, English` and `4, 1, English`. Even better would be having the classes in a seperate table as well and then use `id, student_id, class_id`.

Answer (score 1):

best way is normalize your data. but you can do a litle trick appending `,` to solve this.

this way instead of `TOM` you search for `,TOM,`

```
SELECT tb_student.*
FROM tb_student
JOIN tb_course 
  ON concat(',', namelist, ',') LIKE
                   concat('%,', NAME, ',%') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `FIND_IN_SET` with `INNER JOIN`.

```
 SELECT tb_student.*
FROM
    tb_student
 INNER JOIN  tb_course ON FIND_IN_SET(tb_student.`name`,tb_course.`namelist`) >0
 WHERE tb_course.`title` = 'math'
```

Hope this helps.